# html5 video buffer indicator

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

Im trying to add a buffer loader for all of my videos. All of my videos have got the `id="video"` but only one out of my 6 videos seems to display it. keep in mind i am using chromes network throttle "slow 3g" so i can force a slow buffer. anyone know why only one video will display the loader and none others will?   heres the code:

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
placeholder.style.top = video.offsetTop + "px";
placeholder.style.left = video.offsetLeft + "px";

video.onwaiting = function() {
  showPlaceholder(placeholder, this);
};
video.onplaying = function() {
  hidePlaceholder(placeholder, this);
};

function showPlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.height = vid.scrollHeight + "px";
  img.style.width = vid.scrollWidth + "px";
  img.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.placeholder {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 300000;
}

.THG-video {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
  max-height: 380px;
  max-width: 512px;
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder" class="placeholder"><img src="https://thg-graphics.com/media/DualRing.gif"></div>
<video class="THG-video" id="video" poster="Images/Rita.jpg" controls controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
                <source src="videos/Rita.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
<video class="THG-video" id="video" poster="Images/nat.jpg" controls controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
                <source src="videos/nat_x264.mp4" id="video" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
<video class="THG-video" id="video" poster="Images/ora.jpg" controls controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
                <source src="videos/Ora209_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
<video class="THG-video" id="video" poster="Images/Arff-custom.jpg" controls controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
                <source src="videos/ARFF-Custom-3_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
<video class="THG-video" id="video" poster="Images/THG-Green.jpg" controls controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
                <source src="videos/THG-Green.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
<video class="THG-video" id="video" poster="Images/mgd.jpg" controls controlsList="nodownload noaudio" preload="none">
                <source src="videos/MGD_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
```

Comment: `id` attribute must be unique per document...

Comment: @Kaiido it didnt work changing the name of each "Video" in all the code....

Comment: unless im doing something wrong in the code your idea isnt working.. besides that i dunno how to write js. anyone else able to help me?

Comment: It wasn't an idea, but a fact. I'm not entirely how yoi would like your code to work, you've got only one placeholder element for all vids. But what you will probably want is to get all your elements in an Array like object. For this you can call `document.getElementsByTagName('video')`, and then loop through all the videos to attach the events like you did for the first one, but inside a for loop. I don't have time right now to help you further, sorry.

Comment: if the vid pauses when buffering it adds the spinner logo. if it plays it removes it. it works just only on 1 vid. and i dont know how to add more then one video tag to the main headline such as this: `var video = document.getElementById("video, video1, video2");`that doesnt wanna work. i just want that code linked above to work on every vid i add in the easiest and smallest amount of working code i can get :D

Comment: nothing is working? anyone able to help me with this?

Comment: @Kaiido I got the code working. i posted a answer below. If you check my website iv implemented it and it all works like a charm. you were correct it must be unique. https://thg-graphics.com/portfolio.html  Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a working loader that can be used for as many videos as you like. Just edit the ids, video and placeholder tags to a unique word for each video. Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9faxe587/2/)

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video_1");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder_1");
placeholder_1.style.top = video_1.offsetTop + "px";
placeholder_1.style.left = video_1.offsetLeft + "px";

video_1.onwaiting = function() {
  showPlaceholder(placeholder_1, this);
};
video_1.onplaying = function() {
  hidePlaceholder(placeholder_1, this);
};

function showPlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.height = vid.scrollHeight + "px";
  img.style.width = vid.scrollWidth + "px";
  img.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.display = "none";
}


var video = document.getElementById("video_2");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder_2");
placeholder_2.style.top = video_2.offsetTop + "px";
placeholder_2.style.left = video_2.offsetLeft + "px";

video_2.onwaiting = function() {
  showPlaceholder(placeholder_2, this);
};
video_2.onplaying = function() {
  hidePlaceholder(placeholder_2, this);
};

function showPlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.height = vid.scrollHeight + "px";
  img.style.width = vid.scrollWidth + "px";
  img.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.display = "none";
}


var video = document.getElementById("video_3");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder_3");
placeholder_3.style.top = video_3.offsetTop + "px";
placeholder_3.style.left = video_3.offsetLeft + "px";

video_3.onwaiting = function() {
  showPlaceholder(placeholder_3, this);
};
video_3.onplaying = function() {
  hidePlaceholder(placeholder_3, this);
};

function showPlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.height = vid.scrollHeight + "px";
  img.style.width = vid.scrollWidth + "px";
  img.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.display = "none";
}

var video = document.getElementById("video_4");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder_4");
placeholder_4.style.top = video_4.offsetTop + "px";
placeholder_4.style.left = video_4.offsetLeft + "px";

video_4.onwaiting = function() {
  showPlaceholder(placeholder_4, this);
};
video_4.onplaying = function() {
  hidePlaceholder(placeholder_4, this);
};

function showPlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.height = vid.scrollHeight + "px";
  img.style.width = vid.scrollWidth + "px";
  img.style.display = "block";
}

function hidePlaceholder(img, vid) {
  img.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.placeholder {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  z-index: 300000;
}

.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  background: #ff8000;
  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  width: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}

.loader {
  color: #ff8000;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  margin: 88px auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
}

.loader:before {
  left: -1.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.loader:after {
  left: 1.5em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}

@keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="video_1" controls preload="none">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<div id="placeholder_1" class="placeholder">
  <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</div>

<video id="video_2" controls preload="none">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<div id="placeholder_2" class="placeholder">
  <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</div>

<video id="video_3" controls preload="none">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<div id="placeholder_3" class="placeholder">
  <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</div>

<video id="video_4" controls preload="none">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<div id="placeholder_4" class="placeholder">
  <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
</div>
```